# Cannot set dynamic classname

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [tab, setTab] = useState("tab1");
    
    return(
    <>  
        <a href="#" id="tab1-tab" className="{`someclass ${tab == 'tab1' ? 'active' : ''}`}">Tab1{tab}</a>
        <a href="#" id="tab2-tab">Tab1</a>
    </>
    );
}
```

If I avoid setting dynamic className and having:

```
className="active"
```

for the first tab, then it will be selected (underlined with css)

But doing like above will not select the first tab. As you can see, the useState sets the variable "tab" = "tab1".
It is also printed, and I can see on the page that "tab" is equals to "tab1". However, using ternary operator doesn't seem to work. I have tried many variants, but most of the example show the ternary with boolean values (while in my case it is a string compare) and I don't know if that could be the problem (i.e. the syntax needs to be different).

Comment: u should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx `clsx` for dynamic classes.

Comment: Remove "" in className property, should be className={`someclass ${tab == 'tab1' ? 'active' : ''}`}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use template literals properly:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [tab, setTab] = useState("tab1");
    
    return(
    <>  
        <a href="#" id="tab1-tab" className={`someclass ${tab == 'tab1' ? 'active' : ''}`}>Tab1{tab}</a>
        <a href="#" id="tab2-tab">Tab1</a>
    </>
    );
}
```